# Palindrome python weird

Tags: python

```
array='abcdcba'
array=list(array)
palindrome=[]

for x in range (0,len(array)):
    list1 = []
    list1.append(array[x])
    for y in range(x+1,len(array)):
        list1.append(array[y])
        list2=list1[::-1]
        if list1==list2:
            palindrome.append(list1)
print(palindrome)
```

I'm trying to find the palindromes in the given string, and I'm experiencing weird behaviour.

When I find the palindrome bcdcb, I append the list to the palindrome array.
Then when I append a new value to list1 in the next iteration, the value gets appended to the palindrome list too; making it bcdcba

The same happens to cdc; it prints it as cdcba.

The output I'm getting is:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']]
```

Comment: The `for y in...` loop keeps using the same `list1` on every iteration. Did you mean to put `list1 = []` into that inner loop rather than the outer one?

Answer (score 1):

A usual problem: you have only one list `list1` object (until you re-initialize it with `list1 = []`). To make sure you don't modify the palindromes you've found, just make a copy of `list1` first before you append it, this way when you later modify `list1` that copy won't change:

```
array='abcdcba'
array=list(array)
palindrome=[]

for x in range (0,len(array)):
    list1 = []
    list1.append(array[x])
    for y in range(x+1,len(array)):
        list1.append(array[y])
        list2=list1[::-1]
        if list1==list2:
            palindrome.append(list1[:]) # copy list1
print(palindrome)
```

Comment: Do note there are [arguably better ways to copy lists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/3579910).

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I was able to achieve this:

```
w = input("Type in a word. ")
wL = []
for y in w:
    wL.append(y)
print(wL)
if (wL[::] == wL[::-1]:
    print("This is a palindrome")
else:
    print("This is not a palindrome")
```